# Voting counts frozen

Tags: bug, status-norepro, badges, voting, electorate-badge

It was long (almost two months)  since my count for the electorate badge was 268/600, and since then I've voted on questions and answers almost daily without a big change , now 272/600. My votes on question are 60% of the total and the overall statistics of votes seem to be frozen.

Any idea why that could happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The count for the progress bar is the number of votes on *questions only*.

The badge is awarded for voting on 600 total questions (answers not included), with a secondary requirement of at least 25% of *all of your votes* being on questions. If you've been voting on a lot of answers lately, then that counter won't be increasing.

Your current badge progress matches exactly the number of votes on questions from your account, as indicated in the "Votes Cast" section in the bottom right of your [activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7386695/user10089632?tab=summary).

Comment: Yes, thank you! totally true except the part that I've been voting only for answer, and I've precised the fact that all the statistics seem to be frozen not just that of the electorate badge

Comment: Perhaps you've been voting on a lot of questions that have subsequently been deleted. Those won't count.

Comment: @user10089632 There's just no evidence to suggest that the vote counts are frozen. Everything suggests the counts are updating and accurate, and that you are just mistaken on how many questions you've been voting on.